# Drools: How to set multithreading (multithreadEvaluation) 7.34.0 -Java Maven Spring

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, maven, drools

I see that multithreadEvaluation is set to false by default.
I have a simple Maven Spring Drools implementation using spreadsheet decision tables.

There's not much to it as it's basically a standard installation. I have a restful API and when using jmeter to POST to our endpoint,  the entity is populated and then we fire all rules on it. When using multiple threads in jmeter, I can clearly see that multithreading is not working.

From the documentation:

> You can enable multithreaded evaluation using one of the following options:
> Enable the multithreaded evaluation system property:
> `drools.multithreadEvaluation=true`
>
> Enable multithreaded evaluation while creating the KIE base programmatically:
>
> ```
> KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
> KieBaseConfiguration kieBaseConf = ks.newKieBaseConfiguration();
> kieBaseConf.setOption(MultithreadEvaluationOption.YES);
> KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.newKieBase(kieBaseConf);
> ```

Tried adding `drools.multithreadedEvaluation=true` to application.properties. Didn't resolve the issue.

Tried the second method within the `kieSession()` @Bean, but the kieBase is not used and it didn't resolve the issue. Currently unsure if simply instantiating the KieBase is sufficient. Where should this go? The method returns kContainer.newKieSession() so not sure how to tell if the kieBaseConf.setOption(MultithreadEvaluationOption.YES) actually did anything.

Tried and failed to create a new kieSession prior to fireAllRules. That service is @Autowired to a kieSession @Bean.

First time working with literally this entire tech stack so thank you for taking it slow.

TL;DR Need step by step instructions how to set drools.multithreadEvaluation to true.

Comment: You need to show your actual code for how you're setting up these beans and how you actually fire the rules. The multi-threading is enabled in a per-KieBase basis, so how you've defined your KieBase is important. (Also the property is a _system_ property, not an application property.)

Answer (score 3):

As per documentation Drools expects the *System* property to be set, while you are setting it in `application.properties`, which I assume is Spring-related? Try setting it one of the following ways:

1. When launching your application add "-Ddrools.multithreadEvaluation" to the command line, e.g.:

   `java -Ddrools.multithreadEvaluation <the rest of parameters>`
2. Or set it programmatically on the application start-up early on initialization before any Drools classes are invoked:

   `System.setProperty("drools.multithreadEvaluation", "true");`

Comment: Thank you Stepan, Yes, the application.properties is Spring related. I tried your second approach and I haven't gotten any errors when upping the threads from 2, to 3, to 4 with 4 loop count in jmeter. So, it seems to have worked but I will continue testing.
I put the System.setProperty("drools.multithreadEvaluation", "true"); line immediately after the SpringApplication.run(RulesEngineApp.class, args); line (which was the only line) in the main application class.

Comment: Hm, I'm actually still getting errors with 4 threads and 10 loop. I will keep trying.

Comment: In my controller I `System.out.println(System.getProperty("drools.multithreadEvaluation"));` and it says true when I hit the endpoint but I'm still getting a ton of errors. So the System is setting the property, it's just not working. There currently doesn't seem to be a difference between having this set to true or null (which apparently is the default and not false).

Comment: Seems like there is a method on the RuleBaseConfiguration class setProperty which perhaps I should be setting "drools.multithreadEvaluation", "true" on this rather than the System. Just not sure how, where, or when.

Comment: My rules are not using queries, salience, or agenda groups as mentioned by the documentation these are unsupported.

Comment: The errors are simply returning an object where certain fields are null where they should have been set by the rules. This only happens with more than 2 thread.

Comment: So, it's literally that sometimes it sets the fields on the Entity via a rule and sometimes not. For example, JSON response would be "thing1":true in one outcome and "thing1":null in another outcome when the rules are fired on the exact same object. I thought this was a multithread issue but I'm starting to question it. When I make a new kiebase configuration with the multithreadEvaluation to yes and then create the session from that, the issue persists. If I set it to true via the System.setProperty, I can see that it's set but the issue persists.

Comment: Furthermore, When I have a small number of loops in jmeter, I can usually get no errors even with multiple threads, but ONLY after running jmeter once. The first time it's run, it results in errors. After that it's okay until I up the looks. Again, the "errors" are that the fields are not being set sometimes.

Comment: Doesn't seem like the latest problems you are describing are to do with the original question, you might want to ask a separate question regarding that providing more information and context, such as examples of your rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with -

```
KieHelper kieHelper = new KieHelper();
kieHelper.build( MultithreadEvaluationOption.YES );
```